# wp_list_pages with afc (advanced custom fields)

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

i would use wp_list_pages in sidebar in addition with afc.

the regular output of list pages is something like this

```
<ul>
 <li>page 1</<li>
 <li>page 2</<li>
<ul>
 <li>page 2.1</<li>
 <li>page 2.2</<li>
 <li>page 2.3</<li>
</ul>
 <li>page 3</<li>
 <li>page 4</<li>
 <li>page 5</<li>
 <li>page 6</<li>
</ul>
```

some pages have custom fields and i want something like this

```
<ul>
 <li>page 1</<li>
 <li>page 2 <span> - **custom field info**</span></<li>
<ul>
 <li>page 2.1</<li>
 <li>page 2.2<span> - custom field info</span></<li>
 <li>page 2.3</<li>
</ul>
 <li>page 3</<li>
 <li>page 4<span> - custom field info</span></<li>
 <li>page 5</<li>
 <li>page 6</<li>
</ul>
```

with the regular wordpress custom fields i tried this:

```
wp_list_pages("title_li=".$post->ID."&meta_key=key");
```

but this filters and shows me only the pages with the key and not additional.
how can i solve this little problem? any (other) ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<ul>';

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        if ( get_field( "field_name" ) ) {
            $custom_field_value = ' <span>' . get_field( "field_name" ) . '</span>';
        } else {
            $custom_field_value = '';
        }

        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . $custom_field_value . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';

} else {
    // no posts found
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```